# When to establish database connections with Java/Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am pretty new to Java in general, and have started working with Tomcat for a web app.  One thing I noticed quickly was that my Servlet class is being instantiated once and then reused in future requests.  I discerned this because I was creating the database connection in my constructor, but closing it in the Http methods themselves. This doesn't work, though; the second request fails because the connection has already been closed!

Sure enough, setting a timestamp in the constructor and dumping it out in the Http methods shows the same timestamp in future requests as in the first one.

So now I'm wondering whether I should be establishing my database connection in the constructor and allowing that connection to persist for future requests or if I should be establishing a new connection with each request.

The obvious advantage to establishing the connection in the constructor is that it saves the need for extra connections later, but of course the obvious disadvantage is that the connection is being kept open even when it might not be needed.

What other factors are there in this decision that I might not be considering?  What is the "standard" way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a connection for each request, but use a [connection pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), so that closing the connection doesn't actually close it, but puts it back in a pool of available, open connections.

Note that the most important problem in opening the connection in the constructor as you were doing is not that it's being kept open. The main problem is that two threads, handling two requests for two separate clients, would use the same connection, messing up with each other: an exception in the first thread wuld rollback the changes made by the first thread. Committing in one threads would commit partial changes done in another thread. That's something you must absolutely avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm going through the process of setting up a connection pool right now.  And yes, I absolutely see your point in terms of sharing resources between threads and it is something that had not occurred to me!